# UITableView: How to get all rows for a particular section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**What I want?**
I want to add radio button functionality where a user in particular section can only select one row

[image]

**How am I doing it?**
I added `UISwitch` and based on what row user click I would like to do the following

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 1 || indexPath.section == 2) {

      // disable all the rows of this section except indexPath.row          
    }
}
```

**Where am I stuck?**

How do I get all the rows for a given section in `UITableView`?

P.S: I am a week old to `iOS` and learning, so bear with me if this is a stupid question

Comment: FYI - A `UIPickerView` with the list of choices might be a better option than using 4 rows with switches. Or just show a checkmark in the selected row. Using switches is very non-standard for this.

Comment: @rmaddy, its actually for an homework assignment where I need to align with the `Yelp's` interface

Comment: The easiest way I think is in  your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method call [tableView reloadData]. This will call cellForRowAtIndex for each cell allowing you to enable or disable each cell as required.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)]

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]; i++) {
    if (i != indexPath.row) {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:indexPath.section]];
        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3:**

```
let rowsCount = self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)
    for i in 0..<rowsCount  {
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: indexPath.section)) as! UITableViewCell
        // your custom code (deselecting)
    }
```

Thanks @Soul Clinic for help with this !

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView visibleCellsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSPredicate *visibleCellsInSectionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(UITableViewCell *visibleCell, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [tableView indexPathForCell:visibleCell].section == section;
    }];
    return [tableView.visibleCells filteredArrayUsingPredicate:visibleCellsInSectionPredicate];
}
```

You can put it in a UITableView category if you want.